# CommandButton action doesn't work with custom tag

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, custom-tags

I created the following custom tag:

```html
<h:form>
<d:formBuilder/>        
</h:form>
```

The tag renders without problems like this:

[image: my custom tag]

Tag code:

```
public class FormBuilder extends TagHandler {

    public FormBuilder(TagConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent parent) throws IOException {
        CommandButton command = (CommandButton) context.getFacesContext().getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent( CommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        command.setValue("Click");
        command.setAjax(false);
        MethodExpression me = context.getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{cli.insert}", null, new Class<?>[0]);
        command.setActionExpression(me);

        InputText it = (InputText) context.getFacesContext().getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(InputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);       
        ValueExpression ve1 = context.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{cli.name}", String.class);      
        it.setValueExpression("value", ve1);        

        parent.getChildren().clear();       
        parent.getChildren().add(it);
        parent.getChildren().add(command);
    }

}
```

The managed bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "cli")
public class ClienteController {

    private String name = "aa";

    public String insert() {
        name = "test";
        return "clientes";
    }
}
```

The inputText works correctly but the commandButton doesn't perform the method of managedBean! what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you..  [why command button not getting invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/839393)

Answer (score 0):

the button worked with code:

```
   ExpressionFactory ef = context.getFacesContext().getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(ec, "#{cli.insert}", null, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class});
MethodExpressionActionListener meal = new MethodExpressionActionListener( me );
command.addActionListener(meal);
command.setType( "submit" );
```

Answer (score 0):

curiosly, i had the same problem, but i was using EL expression. I resolved the problem removing the tag "type=button". I know, there is no logic, but only work removing the tag.

P.S: Primefaces 3.4